# Java, clever way to replace "if not null" statement?

Tags: java, polymorphism, dynamic-dispatch

I have a `Vector` full of `long`s.

I would like to be able to always call `getFirstElement()` on a Vector and then perform an action, let's say `addToOtherVector()`. I want to be able to not worry whether or not there is actually a value to return from my original vector. I think I could do it by overriding `addToOtherVector()` like so:

```
//Code to be called when my first vector is not empty
public void addToOtherVector(long s){
    othervector.add(s);
}

//Code to be called when my first vector IS empty
public void addToOtherVector(something???){
    //does nothing
}
```

but I'm not sure what i need to do for the something, as it won't accept `null` as a parameter?

The reason I am doing this is because I don't wish to have to check the size of the vector each time I try to retrieve

Comment: Any solution to this problem will inevitably be more complicated than just doing the null check in an if statement...

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to addToOtherVector() if the get(0) on the first vector is not null?

Comment: @Kal, yes- i thought there could be an elegant solution without having to check the size of the Vector being >0

Comment: @James T -- if your first vector does not have any elements, you will get ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException and not null.

Comment: @James T: I think you are **seriously** confused and should get up to date with current Java practices.  *Vector* is a thing of the past and you should be shot for using it.  But to answer your question: the best way to never have to check for *null* is to make it impossible for your references to be *null*.  The *@NotNull* annotation really helps here: good IDEs will even check your source code (even incomplete *.java* file) and report any *@NotNull* violation in real-time.

Comment: @James T: Did you try to overload `addToOtherVector(long s)` with `addToOtherVector(null n)`?

Comment: This would have been fixed with the `Elvis` operator, which was scrapped for JDK 7, but theoretically is in JDK8.

Comment: @BheshG What? You can't have null as a formal parameter.

Comment: @Kal you will get NoSuchElementException, but otherwise you are on the money: the OP's problem is completely imaginary. Also there is no getFirstElement() method.

Comment: @EJP: I know that's not possible in Java. I was suprised that he gave it a try anyway, may be he did so because he comes from some other programming background where it's possible.

Comment: @BheshG but he didn't 'give it a try'. It was entirely your suggestion.

Comment: @EJP: Read the first line after the code.

Comment: @BheshG OK so he tried it and he already said it didn't work. So why ask about it? Pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the method with a base class. Since `Number` is the base class to `Long`, `Integer`, etc. just use that one :

```
//Code to be called when my first vector is not empty
public void addToOtherVector(long s){
   othervector.add(s);
}

//Code to be called when my first vector IS empty
public void addToOtherVector(Number s){
   if (s == null) {
       return;
   }
   othervector.add(((Number) s).longValue());
}
```

Comment: Collections can't hold primitives so your first overload autoboxes to Long. The second method does the null check the op was hoping to avoid. I don't see how this is a solution...

Comment: both method will add `long` and autoboxing will promote these values to `Long`. Why/how wouldn't this be a solution? From what i understand, the question is just asking so `null` would **not** be added to the vector, which is exactly what this answer does.

Comment: I think he wants a clever way to not do a null check at all by manipulating the overload mechanism somehow

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Vector;
public class Main {

    static Vector otherVector = new Vector();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vector originalVector = new Vector();
        originalVector.add(1);
        originalVector.add(null);
        originalVector.add(2);

        for (Object obj : originalVector) {
            addToOtherVector(obj);
        }
    }

    public static void addToOtherVector(long s) {
        otherVector.add(s);
        System.out.println("adding " + s + " to vector");
    }

    public static void addToOtherVector(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("not adding " + obj + " to vector");
    }
}
```